# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] shows current page

Tags: php, session, http-referer

I have a tracking script that I use to save analytic data to our company database. We have quite a few websites (around 2000 domains) and PPC campaigns and the script I'm using works just fine.

I know that the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is not 100% reliable and can be either empty or spoofed, whatever, that is a small minority of the leads we have coming in (I take this into account in my tracking script).

The problem is that although my `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` var always comes back empty if I echo it out on the affected page, it is passed to the tracking script (via a `$_SESSION` var) as the current page URL. It's as if (note the 'as if', I know this is not the case) PHP is substituting `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` for `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. 
This is from the landing page:

```
$_SESSION['keywords'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
require_once 'tracking.php';
$raw_query = $_SESSION['keywords'];
 $key_browser = getKeywords($raw_query);
 $keywords = $key_browser['keywords'];
 $referer = $key_browser['referer'];
 $user_agent = getBrowserOs($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
 $br = $user_agent['browser'];
 $os = $user_agent['os'];
```

The tracking script is inconsequential because the variables I pass it are not altered.

Comment: Have you considered using google analytics?

Comment: Can you post some relevant code from the script(s) which are causing a problem?

Comment: @Briedis we intensively use GA, but I also program their business software in which they want separate analytic data connected to their individual leads.

Comment: Any redirects taking place? HTTP spec is silent on how referer should be passed along (if at all) when a 302 redirect takes place, so browsers can do whatever they want (pass in original referer, pass in url of redirecting page, pass in nothing, etc...)

Comment: @Marc B No redirects are taking place.

Comment: What do you get if your `print($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` from within the tracking script? I don't quite understand why you are bothering to put the value into `$_SESSION` when you are `require`ing the tracking script, and the value of `$_SERVER` will be the same in the tracking script as it is in the main script - I think this just adds an unnecessary layer of complication...

Comment: I get nothing with a `print_r()` and get `NULL` with `var_dump()`. The reason it's passing it like that is that I use this script for a lot of different websites and not all of them are requiring that tracking script from the first page a user hits (which is the HTTP_REFERER value I want, the search engine query string).

Comment: what about if you do it the same on the line before the `require_once()`?

Comment: I tried it before and after :( I'm starting to think it has something to do with the way PHP is configured on the server.

Comment: it is odd - I can only suggest that you pick the problem site apart one line at a time and print the variables until you find the point at which it gets unset/overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've found no proper solution so I've opted to use a hidden field whose value is populated with javascript's `document.referrer` property and simply passed that to the tracking script. Definitely works although I'm not too pleased that I couldn't find a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

if you load your script with HTML tag like `<script src="mytracking.php"></script>`, referer will be the same as request_uri because request_uri is the one that requests the script.

The only script that gets the referer from which user came if link is clicked is the script that responds to the request from the browser. All resources, loaded via HTML tags will have the current page as referer. Which, by the way, is often used as a protection against hot-linking of images and other resources.

Comment: I don't think that is the case, the HTTP_REFERER is being saved as a $_SESSION var so I can pass it to the tracking script. Although this does sound very close to what is happening.

Comment: What is the server configuration? Do you have nginx in front of apache for example?

Comment: I'm storing $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] directly from index.php and it's always the current url, not anywhere else.